# Android Profiler: No debuggable processes

Tags: android, profiler

It can find my device, but without any debuggable process. It's not the first time this problem occurred. But it still worked yesterday, I used profiler to observe my app's memory info. And when I try to debug my app, the process is debuggable. I tried all solutions just like restart Android Studio, none worked. Does anyone know why?

[image: Android Profiler: No debuggable processes]

[image: Debugger: there is a debuggable process]

Comment: maybe your adb connection is disconnected. so check this in your cmd -> adb devices

Comment: I'm sure adb is active, I can use it to clear app data or restart app. So maybe this is a wrong way, but still thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

In build.gradle(:app) -> find "buildTypes" -> to "debug" section -> set it to "true" -> done

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabe you can Close the AndroidStudio.And then restart the adb service.try again.

Keep your application installed is a Debug mode.

if is done,it will be work. I tried.

Comment: don't open the adb service in command or cmd,just use it in androidstudio.  if it not work. check your computer's port.

Answer (score 0):

Since running apps on an emulator is slow, sometimes you may have more than one instance of your app on the emulator which will cause a problem. Just delete the existing emulator and create a new one, or you can instead just wipe the data on an existing emulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your ADB service by running the following command in your terminal:

`adb kill-server && adb start-server`